# Direction of alignment function in statistical machine translation

Tags: statistical-mt

I'm trying to learn IBM Models and statistical machine translation. I have read various resources and realized that in same articles, alignment function is designed in direction from target language to source language and vice versa in others.

For example; if we are translating from French to English and alignment function is designed in direction from source to target. Then there would be one English token for each French token and we would add a NULL token to English. Because, French word can align with NULL.

I'm pretty confused with direction of alignment function. What is direction of alignment function, are we try to map from source to target or vice versa?